# How can two time series be superimposed in Excel?

Tags: excel, time-series

I have a first time series, with resolution 1 data point per Minute:

```
11.02.16 13:29:00   247.68
11.02.16 13:30:00   398.14
11.02.16 13:31:00   442.12
11.02.16 13:32:00   452.53
11.02.16 13:33:00   449.06
11.02.16 13:34:00   453.69
11.02.16 13:35:00   458.32
11.02.16 13:36:00   453.69
11.02.16 13:37:00   453.69
11.02.16 13:38:00   454.85
11.02.16 13:39:00   454.85
[...] continued
```

can easily be plotted using x-y-diagram.

Now a second time series with less regular data interval (but on the same scale and covering the first time series):

```
11.02.2016 18:04:59 102098.00
12.02.2016 05:51:52 110932.50
12.02.2016 13:31:21 100924.00
12.02.2016 23:37:22 101369.50
12.02.2016 23:38:22 94225.50
13.02.2016 08:36:09 99236.00
13.02.2016 08:36:53 93832.50
13.02.2016 17:20:12 99556.50
```

How can I superimpose the second on the first series? Of course, the y-values would be on primary and secondary axis, but the x-axis (time) is the same dimension.

Comment: 1.  This question has nothing to do with programming, specifically VBA or Formulas in Excel's case.

Comment: 2.  Your data is so disparate in number that it won't look right on a graph.

Answer (score 5):

Give this a try. I made a mock sample for you.

Set up data like this (you don't actually need a secondary axis. I left it there by accident).

[image]

Then make sure to click on **Hidden and Empty Cells** in the Select Data Source Dialog Wizard

[image]

Then choose **Connect Data Points with Line**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

3 step process:

1) Create a chart with the data from the first set of data, above.

2) Right click on the chart, and edit the "Select Data". In there, add in the second set of data (series 2), under series 1. Click OK.

3) Right click on the series 2 graph in the spreadsheet, and click "Format graph". Change the graph from the primary to the secondary axis.

Et voila